# Android list view current position doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm Getting data from my database and pushing them into ListView to view all the data.

Inside my ListView I also have a TextView with the text "Like" in it. Now when I click the like text it will change to "Liked" and I'm updating my like status in my database.

Now my problem is that when i click the "Like" text, the text changes to "Liked" and also it is updated in DB. But also when I scroll through the List View, I can notice other lists' Like text is also changed to Liked. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

I've been trying to get around this problem for quite some days but had no success.

This is my adapter code. At the bottom you can see my onClickListener for the textview

```
package com.mytestapp.myapp;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ForumAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DiscussionList> {
    private static List<DiscussionList> items = null;

    public ForumAdapter(Context context, List<DiscussionList> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static DiscussionList getModelPosition(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public void refill(List<DiscussionList> items) {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        WebView mywebviewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        DiscussionList app = items.get(position);

        if (app != null) {
            TextView titleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dscTitle);
            TextView categoryText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dscCategory);
            TextView descriptionText = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.dscDescription);
            TextView timeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dscTime);
            TextView idText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dscDiscId);
            final TextView likeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.likeText1);
            String like_Status = app.getLikeStatus();

            titleText.setText(app.getTitle());
            categoryText.setText(app.getCategory());
            descriptionText.setText(app.getDescription());
            timeText.setText(app.getTime());
            idText.setText(app.getDiscId());
            if (like_Status == "null") {
                likeText.setText("Like");
            } else {
                likeText.setText("Liked");
            }

            final String dId = app.getDiscId();

            // onClick for image button inside list view

            likeText.setTag(new Integer(position));
            likeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Integer myposition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + dId,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    // .show();
                    likeText.setText("Liked");
                    MainActivity val = new MainActivity();
                    val.updateLikeTable(dId);
                }

            });

        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

And also this is my MainActivity.java file where i update the likes in database

```
package com.mytestapp.myapp;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener {
    public static String strTitle = "0", strCategory = "0",
            strDescription = "0", strTime = "0", strDid = "0";
    Collegemate_DB db = new Collegemate_DB(this);
    int likeStatus = 1;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    public static String usId=null;
    ImageButton imgButton;
    List<DiscussionList> items = new ArrayList<DiscussionList>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_forum_topics);
        usId = db.getCurrentuserId();
        initView();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        /*
         * On click listener to get values from DiscussionList class and send it
         * to another activity when clicking on the list item
         */

        ListView forumList = getListView();
        forumList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Get position of the clicked list item from adapter

                String dTitle, dCategory, dDescription, dTime, dDid;

                DiscussionList accessVar = ForumAdapter
                        .getModelPosition(position);
                dTitle = accessVar.getTitle();
                dCategory = accessVar.getCategory();
                dDescription = accessVar.getDescription();
                dTime = accessVar.getTime();
                dDid = accessVar.getDiscId();

                /*
                 * Storing the forum values in string and passing it to another
                 * activity
                 */

                String values[] = { dTitle, dCategory, dDescription, dTime,
                        dDid };
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForumFullView.class);
                i.putExtra("sendData", values);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        Log.i("j","Inside Init");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "http://example.com/mypath/listData.php?currentUser_id="
                + usId;
        Log.i("Fetch Url : ", url);
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<DiscussionList> data) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ListView forumList = getListView();
        // set the adapter to list
        ForumAdapter adapter = new ForumAdapter(this, data);
        if (forumList.getAdapter() == null) {
            //final ForumAdapter adapter = new ForumAdapter(this, data);
            forumList.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            ((ForumAdapter) forumList.getAdapter()).refill(items);
        }
        // setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void updateLikeTable(String dId,List<DiscussionList> items) {
        try {
            String likeUrl = "http://example.com/mypath/createlike.php?discId="
                    + dId + "&userId=" + usId + "&like_status=" + likeStatus;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(likeUrl));
            client.execute(request);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that the `ListView` widget recycles its views if it can. Once a view is off the screen from scrolling, it goes onto a garbage heap so that when a new view scrolls into place it can be reused, rather than requiring a fresh one to be inflated from scratch. That recycled view is the `convertView` parameter in the `getView()` method. When your `ListView` is first populating, `convertView` will always be null, since the garbage pile has nothing in it, so you're forced to inflate new views, but subsequent calls will likely have that parameter as non-null.

The practical result of this is that when a clicked view that's been set to "Liked" gets recycled, the `TextView` is still there and still populated with "Liked" rather than the presumed default of "Like". So if you click a view, then scroll down so it goes off the screen, it'll come back around and cause the bug you're seeing.

What you'll probably want to do to fix this is to set the text of `likeText` within `getView()` every time, based on what it is in your database. If the post has been liked, set it to "Liked", and if it hasn't, set it to "Like". It should just be one more line, assuming you have easy access to whether or not the post is liked from your `DiscussionList` object.

P.S. As a side note, hard-coded strings are typically frowned upon in Android, so you may want to move your "Liked" string into the resource files. It's not *really* necessary unless you're planning to do translations, but it's still good practice.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that excellent answer. Yes I can set the text of liketext from database itself when creating the list. But what when a user wants to click like for a post that he has not liked already? Now my onCLickListener is also inside my getView() only. Is there a way i can set the text to "Liked" only for the current list item where I'm clicking? Or is there a way to tell android to remember the position of the listview even if it is scrolled?

Comment: As far as I can see, your click listener should be perfectly fine as-is. The `position` variable in `getView()` is going to be absolute within the dataset, and you're getting/using the correct `likeText` and `dId`. Is it not behaving as expected, and if so, what exactly _is_ its current behavior?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. My like and Liked text remains proper now after getting it from DB and showing it in the textview. But now my problem is that when I;m clicking on any list whose liketext is "Like", it updates to "Liked" but when I scroll down and comeback it again changes to "Like". I don't know what's going wrong here.

Comment: I have also updated my adapter file in my question for your reference.

Comment: Your text isn't staying properly updated because you aren't updating your adapter's underlying data, just the database. If you call something to the effect of `app.setLikeStatus()` (whatever you've actually named it) in your click listener so that the object is updated at the same time as the database, it should fix the problem.

Comment: Actually in my on click listener I'm calling another function updateLikeTable which is in another file called MainActivity.java. I tried to use notifyDataSetChanged in the function but still there is no use and the like text behaves the same way. I'm not sure how I should be updating the underlying data. I have edited my question and added the MainActivity.java file.