# Android notifyDataSetChanged() example

Tags: android, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

Can some one give me an example tutorial or guide me in using `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my adapter? I'm getting my data from database and filling my listview. Also in my listview I have a button to like that particular content upon which my database value will be updated and the button text will change to "Liked". But i'm not sure how to refresh my listview again with the data from database.

Comment: Have you tried to use it? Just call that method when your data changes.

Comment: I tried it but my values are not updated. I have put my problem as a question with more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415292/android-list-view-current-position-doesnt-work-properly)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Create custom class for array list in adapter

```
public class Entity   {
int id;
variables ..........
boolean isLiked = false;

public Entity(some values){
  // set the id;
  variables = values ;
}
public void setLiked(boolean like){
   this.isLiked = like; 
   // you must update database here
 }
public boolean IsLiked(){ return this.isLiked; } 

}
```

create custom adapter

```
public class EntityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entity> { 
.................................
........other methods............
.................................

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Entity entity = arrayList.get(position);

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;
     if (view == null) {

        int layoutCode=this.layoutcode;


        view = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutCode, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        assert view != null;


        holder.chkLike=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkLike);

        view.setTag(holder);
     } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
     }


    holder.chkLike.setChecked(entity.IsLiked()); 

    return view;
}
class ViewHolder { 
    CheckBox chkLike;
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    EntityAdapter adapter;
    GridView gridView  = null;


   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       ArrayList<Entity> arraylist = EntityHelper.fetch("select * from entity",this);


      adapter = new EntityAdapter(this, R.layout.item_grid_image, arraylist);


       gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

     gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

             adapter.getItem(pos).setLiked(true);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }


    });
}
```

Comment: I just checked the tutorial. I also checked other similar tutorials like this. All tutorials are explaining Notifydatasetchanged() with an array of some strings from inside java code. In my case I'm getting data from database and that's where I have problems in using Notifydatasetchanged(). Any such tutorials using database??

Comment: Also in all tutorials Notifydatasetchanged() is used when a new item is added to the list. But in my case I'm updating a current list's existing data and trying to refresh list but it wouldn't happen for some reason.